# Display formatted output of a unix command in jsp file

Tags: jsp, format, jsch

I have used JSCH API to ssh to a unix server and execute a command and shell script. I am also able to see the output of the command in my java program as well. I have stored the output in a string variable. I am passing this string variable that has the output of the unix command, to the JSP file.

However when i do <% =string %> in jsp , the output is in single line. but when i print the same string variable in my java program like system.out.println(string), the output is in a formatted way. the output in the system console is same as the output displayed in putty.

Please help me how do i format the string in jsp so that the out put is same as that of the console.

Comment: Replacing all \n with <br/> might be a start. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: thanks Alan - it did help. but why would the jsp unformat the string when it is displaying in webpage ?

Comment: thanks alan, i am able to resolve it, as i put in the <div> element and gave the alignment : left. also the <br/> element helped. ty